# Sort posts by category name and title

Tags: wp-query, query, sort

Trying to figure out how I can output my posts based on category title (a–z) and secondly, the title of the posts within the category:

A CATEGORY
– A post beginning with a
– Because I want to be output second
– Come on, and output me already

B CATEGORY
– Another post beginning with a
– Bother, can't come up with another title on B
– I guess you get the point

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever follow up on the answer? Was it the solution? If not: why?

Answer (score 6):

To get them broken down by Category, you need to loop through the list of categories and then query on each category:

```
$categories = get_categories( array ('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'asc' ) );

foreach ($categories as $category) {

   echo "Category is: $category->name <br/>";

   $catPosts = new WP_Query( array ( 'category_name' => $category->slug, 'orderby' => 'title' ) ); 

   if ( $catPosts->have_posts() ) {

       while ( $catPosts->have_posts() ) {
          $catPosts->the_post();
          echo "<a href='the_permalink()'>the_title()</a>";
       }

       echo "<p><a href='category/$category->slug'>More in this category</a></p>";

   } //end if
  


} //end foreach

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: For scalability, I don't recommend using multiple `WP_Query` items when not needed.. Using a single `get_terms` and a single `WP_Query` is all you need. Then you have all items, and can use `array_filter` to figure out which posts are in each category.

Answer (score 1):

I think do you mean `GROUP Post` by category/taxonomy `NOT SORT`.

Here, Is a code to `GROUP` by `category/taxonomy`

1. `$terms = get_terms( 'my_cat_name' );`

Here, `cat_name` name is the name of taxonomy, When you register it like this: e.g.

```
register_taxonomy( 'my_cat_name', array( 'custom_post_name' ), $args )
```

2. Use it in `Query` e.g.:

   ```
   $args = array(
      'post_type'  => 'custom_post_name',
      'my_cat_name' => $term->slug,
      'posts_per_page' => $no_of_posts,
   );
   ```
3. Complete code:

   ```
   $terms = get_terms( 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_SLUG' );

   if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){

       $output .= '<ul class="category-list">';
       foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

           $output .= '<li class="single-cat">';
           $output .= '    <h3>' . $term->name . '</h3>';  //  Taxonomy/Category Name

               $args = array(
                   'post_type'     => 'POST_TYPE_SLUG',
                   'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_SLUG' => $term->slug,
                   'posts_per_page' => -1,
               );    

               $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

               if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                   $output .= '<ul class="cat-post-list">';
                   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                       $the_query->the_post();
                       $output .='     <li class="cat-single-post">';
                       $output .='         <h4><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' .get_the_title(). '</a></h4>';
                       $output .='     </li><!-- .cat-single-post -->';
                   }
                   $output .= '</ul><!-- .cat-post-list -->';
               } 
               wp_reset_postdata();
           $output .= '</li><!-- .single-cat-item -->';
       }
       $output .= '</ul><!-- .category-list -->';
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Maheshwaghmare's work;

```
<? 
$terms = get_terms( 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ){ ?>

<div class="POST_TYPE_PLURAL">

<?  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
//print_r($term) // DEBUG;
$term_slug = $term->slug;
$term_name = $term->name;
$term_description = $term->description;
?>

    <div class="POST_TYPE_CATEGORY <?=$term_slug; ?>">

      <h1 class="section-head"> <?=$term_name; ?> </h1>
      <p><?=$term_description; ?> </p>

       <?  
        $args = array(
          'post_type'     => 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
          'tax_query' => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => $term_slug,
            ),
          ),
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
         );    

         $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

           if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
              <? while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

               <div class="POST_TYPE_SINGLE">
                <h3> <? the_title(); ?> </h3>
                <? // MORE TEMPLATING CODE ?>
               </div>

             <?  endwhile;
           endif;
           wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
     </div>
 <?  } // foreach
 } //if terms
 ?>
```

Comment: I would be interested to know whether it's better practice to keep making instances of wp_query or whether it would be better to make an array from one and then use the array to populate.

Comment: It would be better if you can explain the code you posted and what have you expanded from previous answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `orderby` parameter for a new `wp_query` instance:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

Soo for every category use a separate instance.

More information here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query