# Sort custom posts by date and then by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, sort

i am having this issues for month and i can't figure out how to solve this one:

I am working on a website, where you can check out cultural events in my region. This is just to let you know of what i'm talking about in general .
[mox-veranstaltungen.de](https://www.mox-veranstaltungen.de)

Now for the backend i have made a custom query to output a list of events by a given range of dates. These dates are actually the eventdates. (when those events take place) There are several events on one specific day.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>  'events',
    'numberposts'   =>  20,
    'meta_key'  =>  'date',
    'orderby'   =>  'meta_value_num',
    'order'     =>  'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       =>  'date',
            'value'     =>  array ($von,$bis),
            'compare'   =>  'BETWEEN',
            'type'      =>  'NUMERIC',
        ),
        )
```

the date value is made with ACF and sorting on dates just works fine.

Now every event has also a taxonomy term of a taxonomy i called 'eventtype'. I need to sort events of a specific date to these taxonomy terms.

For example:

1. all events happen on the 4th of july

   - All events with the taxonomy term 'music'
   - All events with the taxonomy term 'plays'
   - All events with the taxonomy term 'fairs'
   - ...

I don't know how to solve this. I've extended the query above with this tax_query statement, which obviously is not working:

```
$allGenres = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'eventtype','fields'  =>'ids','hide_empty' => false));

$args = array(
    'post_type' =>  'events',
    'numberposts'   =>  20,
    'meta_key'  =>  'date',
    'orderby'   =>  'meta_value_num',
    'order'     =>  'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       =>  'date',
            'value'     =>  array ($von,$bis),
            'compare'   =>  'BETWEEN',
            'type'      =>  'NUMERIC',
        ),
        ),
        'tax_query' =>  array (
        array(
        'taxonomy'  =>  'eventtype', //taxonomy
        'field'     =>  'term_id',
        'terms'     =>  $allGenres //
        'orderby'   =>  array ('terms' => 'ASC')
        )
));
```

This orderby statement is just a shot in the dark, just some filthy code googling :)
How i am solving this? I can imagine it's just a quite easy task, right?
I am not a programmer but in some way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll be able to organize by category using a single query. You may need to sort by category first, then by date (or vice versa). I've taken the code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124037/sort-posts-by-category-name-and-title/145385) and applied it to your situation, though the reverse may work better for you.

```
// First get all the categories
$categories = get_categories( array ('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'asc' ) );

// Then for each category, run a query inside of it
foreach ($categories as $category) {

   echo "Category is: $category->name <br/>";

   $catPosts = new WP_Query( 
                   array ( 
                       'category_name' => $category->slug,
                       'orderby' => 'title' ) ); 

   if ( $catPosts->have_posts() ) {

       while ( $catPosts->have_posts() ) {
          $catPosts->the_post();
          echo "<a href='the_permalink()'>the_title()</a>";
       }

       echo "<p><a href='category/$category->slug'>More in this category</a></p>";

   } //end if
  


} //end foreach

wp_reset_postdata();
```